# Data type to store html code in cassnadra

Tags: cassandra, richtext, complex-data-types, nosql

What's the best way to store html code in cassnadra?

I want to put a minified text of HTML into a database row, what kind of data should i use in cassnarda?

Comment: use text data type

Comment: `text` data type requires data in valid UTF-8 encoding. for HTML pages the blob could be better choice

Answer (score 2):

You can use text/varchar datatype, but checking and validating all escape characters on insert can be a real pain. I think it is easier just to use blob.

Cassandra data types:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html